# Hot to make this style border when I hover into an HTML element

Tags: html, css, hover

Help me to create this style hover css. Thanks all !

[image: very impressive hover style]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you add some of your code? That you've tried? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm noob so I have no idea for this :(

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use two divs that overlap, one covers the other but has rounded corners to display the borders of the lower div:

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/vwnp08o0/)

```css
 #div1{
      position:absolute;
      top:9px;
      left:9px;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      background-color:white;
    
    }
    
    #div1:hover{
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    
    #div2 {
      position:relative;
      top:-1px;
      left:-1px;
      height:102px;
      width:102px;
      background-color:white;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="div1"/>
<div id="div2"/>
```

Comment: @TrungVuHuu Updated answer to contain html